# backbone.js and MVC - multiple pages

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I have looked through backbone.js and am a little confused, is it specifically for creating 1 page websites, or can it be used to create dynamic page updates (like say the facebook newsfeed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone isn't specifically for creating 1 page websites. It basically helps you create dynamic pages and if you want expand that to your whole site and make it a one page site, thats possible also.